# Delete a Microsoft Teams channel message using the Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is it currently possible to delete a message from a channel, using the Graph REST API?

I can retrieve a message with GET:

```
GET /teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages/{message_id}
```

But the corresponding DELETE fails with a 404 error:

```
DELETE /teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages/{message_id}  # fails
```

I'm using the beta API, if it matters. I'm also the author of the message in question.

Comment: There is no such API as of now that deletes channel message. There is already feature request present in [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/42304687-graph-api-support-for-delete-and-update-of-channel). Upvote it so that it may be implemented in the future by Product Team.

Comment: Until now if I were to delete the existing message on the channel....I sent another message to the existing one(as a REPLY) using Graph API...stating..."this chat is deleted" in BOLD. I know they have almost every api for the channel thread but not to delete. Cant wait for them to release that feature

Comment: Yeah, i agree with you. I would stick with what @ShivaKeshavVarma suggested above, so that they consider implementing it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-softdelete is in beta

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer for better visibility

There is no such API as of now that deletes channel message. There is already feature request present in [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/42304687-graph-api-support-for-delete-and-update-of-channel). Upvote it so that it may be implemented in the future by Product Team.

Comment: This Forum link gives error saying "This UserVoice instance is no longer available." Is there a different place to raise a feature request for Delete message api ?